# Html navbar with mobile support and logo

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar

I want a navbar on my site but cant figure it out i want it to look something like
[this](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav)
But i want to have a logo on it to so that is the problem i have. It should look something like the bottom one on this [site](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html#!)

Comment: Do you have any code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/, and you can learn to use bootstrap to creat things such as navbars easily.

Put this at the top of your html script in the head section for bootstrap to work or download bootstrap and put it in your project folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Here is an example using bootstrap.

```
        <!--appear when room to display is smaller-->

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Your Logo</a>
      </div>


      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active">
            <a href ="put your link here">
              Item 
            </a>
          </li>

     <!--align content to the right-->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active">
          <a href ="">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
            Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href ="">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
            Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```